# How to solve Error installing package lidR in R?

Tags: r, package, lidar, lidr

I am using amazon sagemaker notebook instance. And i am trying to install lidR package into R notebook but i got following errors.
How can i. Solve it?

Code;

```
install.packages("lidR")
```

Error;

```
installing the dependencies ‘units’, ‘lwgeom’, ‘raster’, ‘sf’, ‘stars’, ‘terra’
    
    
    Warning message in install.packages("lidR"):
    “installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status”
    Warning message in install.packages("lidR"):
    “installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status”
    Warning message in install.packages("lidR"):
    “installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status”
    Warning message in install.packages("lidR"):
    “installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status”
    Warning message in install.packages("lidR"):
    “installation of package ‘lwgeom’ had non-zero exit status”
    Warning message in install.packages("lidR"):
    “installation of package ‘stars’ had non-zero exit status”
    Warning message in install.packages("lidR"):
    “installation of package ‘lidR’ had non-zero exit status”
    Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
    
    Making 'packages.html' ...
     done
```

Comment: Is that the entire output? Normally the specific error is included somewhere in the output. This just seems to be the final lines that a failure occurred somewhere but does not say what the failure is.

Comment: @MrFlick this is the only output that shown :/

Comment: @MrFlick the same line works normal for ex in kaggle notebook.

Comment: Those are all moderately more-complex packages _with build-dependencies_ you will have to take care of.  You can search for posts on individual package, for example `sf` or `units`.  And importantly, you can see more if you break it down.  Start with, say, `install.packages("units")` and you will likely see an error that you need the 'udunits' library.  So install that, try again. And on to the next package.  (Aside: there are some Linux flavours for which you can get binaries:  Fedora, OpenSUSE and now Ubuntu -- see https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/)

Comment: Just an option to consider. You might be lacking some libraries like `libudunits` or `libgdal`. They are installed outside the R environment.

Answer (score 1):

Use conda to install the package

Open a terminal on your JupyterLab instance and run the following commands:

```
conda init bash
source ~/.bashrc
conda activate R
conda install -c conda-forge r-lidr
```

You should be able to library(lidR) on your notebook after that (restart the R kernel if needed)